# I'm almost 100% sure that the answer is 60 and yet I got the question wrong.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For context here's the typed-out question: Consider rectangle PQRS (not shown) with PQ=24 and PS=10. If A and B are the midpoints of sides PQ and QR respectively, find AB.

I'm really not sure what I could be doing wrong and in all probability I'm most likely overlooking one very small and crucial detail or definition that's embedded in the question. Half of 24 and 10 is 12 and 5 respectively and when multiplied together 12 times 5 will equal 60. Is that not the question, find A and B, midpoints, and then multiply them together?

I've just now gotten the idea that maybe PQ=24 means that they're variables that when multiplied together equal 24 but that doesn't make sense because then it mentions line PQ's midpoint, ie P and Q are not variables. It's a simple question but I can't seem to get past it, please help me.

[image: the question]

Comment: It should be a geometry problem, but you understand it as algebra... (A and B are the midpoints, not two numbers)

Comment: Please write an informative title... one that relates to the content of the question.

Comment: AB is the length of the line segment between A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ in this case means the length from point $A$ to point $B$. It doesn't mean the area of something like a sub-rectangle of the main rectangle, $A\times B=60$.

To get the length from $A$ to $B$ you need to use Pythagoras' theorem. 12 and 5 is a well-known combination. You need to solve for $\sqrt{12^2+5^2}$.

Comment: While your intent is correct, "$A \times B = 60$" is not true. $A$ and $B$ are points, not numbers. There is no such concept as "$A \times B$".

Comment: Yes, we can be fairly sure that AB doesn't mean $A\times B$ in this case, since $A$ and $B$ are points. I think you've parsed the first sentence wrongly. What I have written is that AB probably means "the length from point A to point B" rather than "the area of a sub-rectangle, which is A×B=60". You seem to have taken that to mean that I think that such a subrectangle exists, but I am actually stating that it doesn't, and that that is a misinterpretation of what $AB$ means.

Comment: I didn't misinterpret your post. I started out by saying your intent was correct. But still, your writing that "$A \times B = 60$" is the area of a subrectangle confuses the matter, rather than clarifying it. The subrectangle exists (though it is not what the question asks for) and its area is $60$, but its area is not expressible as "$A \times B$".

Comment: @PaulSinclair OK I have rewritten it, although I think that it is very unlikely that anyone was actually confused by the previous version. Hopefully this discussion can be ended. Thank you for your input and I hope to see you on some more interesting discussions again.

Comment: You wouldn't be confused and I wouldn't be confused. But the idea that $A$ and $B$ were lengths instead of points was the key mistake that led to the OP asking this question. And way you had originally phrased that paragraph reinforced this error even though you were trying to correct it. Now it is better.